# Java - putting comma separated integers from a text file into an array

Tags: java, arrays, file, integer

Had a quick question based on an assignment I'm working on.

I have a list of numbers like this in a text file:

```
5, 8, 14
7, 4, 2
```

And I need them inserted into an array as such

```
joe[5][8] = 14; 
joe[7][4] = 2;
```

Having trouble getting this done, thanks to anyone who can give me a hand.

-Edit-

This is the code I have now

```
File f = new File("solution.txt");
Scanner sc = new Scanner(f);      

while(sc.hasNextLine())
{
    if(sc.hasNextInt())
        x = sc.nextInt();

    if(sc.hasNextInt())
        y = sc.nextInt();

    if(sc.hasNextInt())
        joe[x][y] = sc.nextInt();
}
```

Comment: Can you give an example of what the whole arrays should be with this example.

Comment: "*Having trouble getting this done*" is not precise problem description. What trouble do you have? Can we see your code? BTW to add more info use [edit] option placed below your post.

Comment: At what point are you getting tied up?  Do you have code that reads in the numbers from a file?  Are you not sure how to create the array dynamically?

Comment: Read the file line by line and store the 3 numbers in variables `i`, `j` ,`k`, then loop over the array with `joe[i][j] = k`.

Comment: Have you tried using `Scanner`? Something like `Scanner sc = new Scanner (new FileReader(<fileName>))` ; `sc.useDelimiter("[,]+")` ; `while sc.hasNext()...` Are you looking for a question about this?

Answer (score 1):

Try instantiating a 2 dimensional array then reading each line, and then each of the three numbers from each line. Use the first 2 numbers as the array indices and the last as the value.

Some example code

```
int[][] numbers = new int[1000][1000];
File fin = new File("filename");
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fin));

String line = null;
while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
    String tokens[] = line.split(", ");
    int numberOne = Integer.parseInt(tokens[0]);
    int numberTwo = Integer.parseInt(tokens[1]);
    int numberThree = Integer.parseInt(tokens[2]);
    numbers[numberOne][numberTwo] = numberThree;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Take an entire line an split the line into a String array using the method `split` as exemplified below. Then take each element of the String array and convert it to an `int` using the method `Integer.parseInt(  )`. Your code should look something like:

```
File f = new File("solution.txt");
Scanner sc = new Scanner(f);      

while(sc.hasNextLine())
{
    String line = sc.nextLine();
    String[] number = line.split(", ");
    int x = Integer.parseInt(number[0]);
    int y = Integer.parseInt(number[1]);
    joe[x][y] = Integer.parseInt(number[2]);
}
```

Comment: It should be `line.split(", ");` instead of `line.split(",");`

Comment: It does not matter since at the moment Integers are being parsed the white space would be ignored.

Comment: No, it will throw a `NumberFormatException` since the value represented by the `String` is not an `int` (caused by the whitespace). You should either call `trim()` on the `String`s before parsing or change the regex of the `split()` method (as I suggested earlier).

Comment: You are right. I made a bad mistake of thinking that. I just tried out some code. Thank you for helping me learn this

Answer (score 0):

You have to specify the `,` as a separator.

Try this: `sc.useDelimiter("[,]+");`

Then your code is:

```
File f = new File("solution.txt");
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(f);  
    sc.useDelimiter("[,]+");    


  while(sc.hasNextLine())
  {
    if(sc.hasNextInt())
    x = sc.nextInt();
    else {}
    if(sc.hasNextInt())
    y = sc.nextInt();
    else{}
    if(sc.hasNextInt())
    joe[x][y] = sc.nextInt();
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

This may not be the most efficient way but it allows for unknown array distentions.

```
public int[][] loadArray(String file) {
    File fin = new File(file);
    BufferedReader br = null;
    try {
        br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fin));
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    int width = 1;
    int[][] numbers = new int[1][1];
    String text = null;
    try {
        while ((text = br.readLine()) != null) {
            String i[] = text.split(", ");
            int a = Integer.parseInt(i[0]);
            int b = Integer.parseInt(i[1]);
            if (a > numbers.length) numbers = new int[a][width];
            if (b > width) {
                numbers = new int[numbers.length][b];
                width = b;
            }
            numbers[a][b] = Integer.parseInt(i[2]);
        }
    } catch (NumberFormatException | IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return numbers;
}
```